# JQuery Autocomplete with remote Data Source

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am having a problem with JQuery Autocomplete with remote data source. I see that there are request being made each time I start typing, however, I don't get any visible JQuery output. Can anybody help?

The code that perfomrs search:

```
 $term=$_GET['term'];
 $query = "SELECT Items.ItemID, Items.ItemCode, Items.ItemDescription FROM     
 Items WHERE Items.ItemCode LIKE '%$term%' ";
 $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->store_result();
 $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
 $stmt->bind_result($ItemID, $ItemCode, $ItemDescription);

 for ($i=0; $i <$numrows; $i++) {
         $stmt->fetch();

     $arr[] = array(
             "value" => strval($ItemCode),
             "label" => strval($ItemDescription)
   );
 }
     header("Content-Type", "application/json");
     echo json_encode($arr);
```

I get the following JSON output:

```
[{"value":"1085","label":"Item1"},{"value":"2089","label":"Item2"}]
```

I have the following code for JQuery:

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#items" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax( {
          url: "../items-search.php",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            term: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( data );
          }
        } );
      },
      minLength: 1,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( "Selected Item: " + ui.item.value   );
      }
    } );
  } );
  </script>
```

And HTML for divs:

```
  <div>
  <label for="items">Item: </label>
  <input id="items">
</div>

<div>
  Result:
  <div id="log"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out on my own. I changed `jsonp` to `json` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your html you have an id `birds`, but nowhere an id `items`. Is it at all possible that you copied a jQuery UI example and forgot to change that? :-)